# Why does Jekyll create new directories with index.html files in them when I create a new post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, jekyll

Am I missing a setting somewhere? When the site is generated, the markdown files in the _posts directory get converted to directories themselves. Each of those directories has an index.html file in it with the content.

I would obviously just prefer for the posts to be generated without creating a new directory for each post.

Answer (score 10):

This has to do with the way you are configuring permalinks to have pretty permalinks. If you want don't want pretty permalinks and you just want to have .html files on their own and not in their own directories, in your _config.yml file try changing

```
permalink: pretty
```

to

```
permalink: date
```

or

```
permalink: none
```

Comment: Anyway to make it simply /title with just files and not file-in-folders?

Comment: try    permalink: /:title.html

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with the directories? If you don't want your posts to end .html (which I assume that you don't) then surely you need to use the directory/index.html for it reliably to work without dependence on the particulars of a given webserver. Directories are cheap. You may as well make use of them - it's not like you're rooting through the _site directory manually.